# Compute Kendall's Tau for a list of list

Tags: python, scipy, correlation

I created a model that can order objects of different length, and I want to measure its performance. The model receive as an input a scrambled objects and output the objects that are ordered. For example, I have as an input x= [[ 5, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2], [3,2,4,1], [2,1,3],.....] and the output is y=[[5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4], [ 1,3, 2, 4], [1,2,3].....]
I want to use the Kendall's tau to compute the correlation of the list x and y. But I am not sure if I can do that, because many examples in the web showing use of Kendall's Tau with only 1D list, so should I compute Kendall's Tau for every list separately and average them? and if I don't have to do them separately, how can I deal with the different length lists?
I tried to do scipy.stat.kendalltau(x,y) but it gives me an error because of the different lengths of lists.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each element of x and y are lists of the same length. You just need to iterate over the lists in parallel using `zip`.

```
from scipy import stats

x= [[ 5, 6, 4, 3, 1, 2], [3,2,4,1], [2,1,3]] 
y=[[5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4], [ 1,3, 2, 4], [1,2,3]]

for l1, l2 in zip(x, y):
    print(stats.kendalltau(l1, l2))

KendalltauResult(correlation=0.6, pvalue=0.1361111111111111)
KendalltauResult(correlation=-0.6666666666666669, pvalue=0.3333333333333333)
KendalltauResult(correlation=0.33333333333333337, pvalue=1.0)
```

Comment: I want to compute the Kendall's Tau for the whole lists x and y as one numbers. I have around 4,846 lists in x and in y, so I don't want to have 4,846 Kendall's tau for every element. I hope this is clear.